# is it possible to match something with a linebreak in 1 line?

Tags: html, lua

i use a get request to get data from a page and i need to match the data and its like this

```
<tr>
<td>Level</td>
<td>3303</td>
</tr>
```

so in lua i tried to match like this

```
local info = {
  ["Level"] = {str = 'Level</td><td>(%d+)<' }
             }

local result = string.gsub(tostring(data), "%,", "")
    for k, s in pairs(info) do
      for r in string.gmatch(result, s.str) do
          if k == "Level" then
```

So basically im trying to get the '3303' number, so i have doubt how to represent the lineabreak from Level to 3303

Comment: probably with \n ?

Comment: lol I already thought about it but I didn't think it would work, but it works ty

Comment: Please don't parse HTML with patterns...

Comment: Its for a script inside a game client so dont worry.

Comment: I wanna point to the gsub(Pattern, Replace, ```Count```) Argument. If you do ```str:gsub("\n", "", 1)``` then gsub() will stop/return after first pattern match/replace.

Comment: A linebreak is a space-ish character, so the following pattern will work too: `'Level</td>%s*<td>(%d+)<'`